# How to update a column of a temp table by joining 2 seperate tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I update a temp table column by joining 2 separate tables?

I had something like this -

```
UPDATE t
SET t.ContactCode = PC.Code
FROM @tempUsers t,
Users U LEFT JOIN PhoneCodes PC ON U.ContactCodeId = PC.PhoneCodes_Id
```

So here, @tempUsers is my temp table and Phone Codes and Users are two different tables.

This is running with no syntax error, but the column values are all displaying as null, which is not correct.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the query.

Comment: `@tempUsers t, Users U` is an old-style cross-join, which was probably not the intent. Use proper join syntax. Also `LEFT JOIN PhoneCodes PC` means that there may not be a result, so any non-joined value will be null

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a joining column between @tempUsers and users table to update @tempUsers **(where t.userid=u.id)**.

```
update @tempUsers
       set t.ContactCode = PC.Code
from Users U 
     LEFT JOIN PhoneCodes PC 
          ON U.ContactCodeId = PC.PhoneCodes_Id 
     where @tempUsers.userid=u.id
```

It would be better if you share structures of those three tables along with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper JOINs, then you would have seen that you didn't define a condition to join the table Users.

You are looking for something like this :

```
UPDATE T SET T.ContactCode = PC.Code
FROM @tempUsers T
     INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Code = T.UserCode
     LEFT JOIN PhoneCodes PC ON PC.PhoneCodes_Id = U.ContactCodeId
```